# Hibernate option doesn't appear in the shutdown menu(s)

Tags: shutdown, hibernate, 13.10

In 13.04, I enabled hibernation by following [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.10/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html) instructions:

> You can also enable the hibernate option in the menus. To do that, use your favorite text editor to create /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla. Add the following to the file and save:
>
> ```
> [Re-enable hibernate by default]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
> ResultActive=yes
> ```

It worked fine in 13.04, but after upgrading to 13.10, the "hibernate" option no longer appears in the top right corner shutdown/login menu and neither in the menu that comes up when I press the laptop's power button ([image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9vpF.png)). Yes, I have checked that the the `.pkla` file is still there untouched. What could be the problem?

Hibernate itself still works when I do it from the terminal with `pm-hibernate`.

**Edit:** similar question: [Hibernation is still missing from menu in 13.10 after enabling via polkit. How to enable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361734/)

Comment: This has been filed as a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/1232814

Comment: according with the answer this is a bug.

Comment: @Braiam I've seen that now. There is also [a similar question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/361734/hibernation-is-still-missing-from-menu-in-13-10-after-enabling-via-polkit-how-t).