# Hibernation is still missing from menu in 13.10 after enabling via polkit. How to enable?

Tags: 13.10, power-management, indicator, hibernate

I know that since 12.04, we need to add a policykit rule to enable hibernation (see question [How to enable hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation) and the [Official Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html)).

I can successfully bring my laptop into hibernation mode with `sudo pm-hibernate` or `sudo s2disk`, so the rule is in place and works, but the hibernation entry is still missing in the menu.

I can tell from looking through the source of the indicator-session package (but not understanding the whole code) that there is still a hibernation menu entry in the code and it should be displayed when the system is capable of hibernating. Please calm down if you're enraged by this. **This is very unlikely to be a conspiracy**, but rather a bug/regression on a deeper level, which can happen when you move code around or replace it.

**Question:** What needs to be done in 13.10 to properly tell `indicator-session` that the system can hibernate?

---

Possible duplicate: [Hibernation still not available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313438/hibernation-still-not-available) - No activity, because saucy was in development at that time, so out of scope for AskUbuntu.

Related bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/1232814

Comment: My question about the same thing: http://askubuntu.com/questions/361058/

Comment: @pileofrocks Sorry, must have overlooked yours in my feed reader today.

Comment: Yours is worded in a better way though and more technically (made my question when I wasn't aware of the bug yet), if other one should be closed, then it should the one made by me. :P

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## 14.04 and beyond

Mitch points out in his answer for 14.04 and 16.04 that you should check `10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla` before modifying anything. Also check that you have Secure Boot disabled and if that brings the menu option back.

## Re-enabling the hibernation option in the menu

To re-enable the hibernation option in the menu, your `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` should be modified to look like the following in saucy (13.10):

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Then reboot or run `killall indicator-session-service` in your session and you should have your hibernate functionality/menu option back. Create the file if it doesn't exist already.

### Investigation from bug report

Citation from Jeffery To's post on Launchpad [Bug Report #1232814](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1232814/comments/13):

> For Saucy, indicator-session was updated to use logind
>   (org.freedesktop.login1) instead of upower.
>
> If you check
>   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla,
>   you'll see that hibernate is disabled by default in both upower and
>   logind.
>
> So the first step to re-enable the Hibernate option is to edit
>   /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
>   to something like:
>
> ```
> [Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
> ResultActive=yes
>
> [Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
> ResultActive=yes
> ```
>
> After rebooting, the login screen session menu should have a Hibernate
>   option.
>
> [...]

All thanks and credit go to Jeffery!

### Why was hibernation disabled?

There exists a bug report on launchpad that suggests disabling suspend/hibernate instead of tracking which hardware "certifies" for which power modes. It's claimed to be a more scalable approach.

Another thing to mention is that using UEFI Secure Boot and hibernation appears to be possible but may be a risk to circumvent the former. ([1](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/UEFI_Secure_Boot_Guide/sect-UEFI_Secure_Boot_Guide-Implementation_of_UEFI_Secure_Boot-Kernel.html#sect-UEFI_Secure_Boot_Guide-Implementation_of_UEFI_Secure_Boot-Restrictions), [2](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sled-12/book_sle_admin/data/sec_uefi_secboot.html)) As a reminder, when you use hibernation you store everything in RAM to disk without encryption, this includes passwords for encrypted filesystems and containers.

**At some point with 16.04 I had to disable Secure Boot** to be able to hibernate my laptops. In my case I used uswsusp and testing with s2disk returned the message below. This may give you a hint that your issue, why you can't hibernate although everything else is in place, is related to Secure Boot:

```
s2disk: Could not open the snapshot device. Reason: Operation not permitted
```

However, please understand that this is not a place to complain and please be nice.

### Related questions

- [How can I tell Ubuntu to do nothing when I close my laptop lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid) (or tell Ubuntu to hibernate when closing the laptop lid)

Comment: Thanks for the method, but I'm still having no success after a reboot and after 'killall indicator-session-service'.  You did mention "or do other troubleshooting after reboot", though, so I guess I'm in that category.  It's very strange to find such an important behavior *still* unsupported after so many iterations of this operating system, but that's all the rant I've got at the moment.  I'll just cross my fingers and stick with sudo pm-hibernate for now.

Comment: A couple of questions: why in the world is hibernation disabled? And does doing the above avail hibernation options in Power Settings? I don't need hibernation in the gear menu, but for the my laptop to hibernate at critical battery levels. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I'm not responsible for this change but the initial question here on AskUbuntu contains a link to a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-desktop-privileges/+bug/812394) that suggests disabling suspend/hibernate instead of tracking which hardware "certifies" for for what power modes, since that approach seems to be more scalable. I would rather blame the manufacturers here. I have hibernate as an option for what to do on critical battery levels on my desktop, but couldn't replicate this in my VM to add a proper english screenshot.

Comment: I am not able to hibernate even after this!! :( please help! hibernation works on my machine...but not showing in the menu..

Comment: I upgraded from 13.04 and have no such file: `➜  ~  sudo ls /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
ls: cannot access /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla: No such file or directory`. Should I just create it?

Comment: @constantius Yes, you should create it.

Comment: Doesn't fix hibernate being missing from power settings :(

Comment: @SalmanPK Did you try any of the other answers?

Comment: @Seth, yup to no avail.

Comment: @SalmanPK You might ask another question then. Also make sure you have enough SWAP.

Comment: @Seth Actually, I just tried the "Related question" and it worked, thanks! Now my laptop hibernates on closing lid. \o/

Comment: @SalmanPK Can I know which one?

Comment: @Seth This: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15520/how-can-i-tell-ubuntu-to-do-nothing-when-i-close-my-laptop-lid

It's actually about doing nothing on closing the lid but I tailored it to hibernate instead.

Comment: Is this necessary on 14.04?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the recipe.

I would like to leave some traces of the modifications. Do you know how can I add comments in the pkla file?

Comment: @MathieuDubois Have you tried using `#`? It seems to be valid for PolicyKit .conf files like `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/50-localauthority.conf`, `;` may also work or be worth a try as the format looks similar to [INI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, INI is rather loosely defined. Anyway I have added some comments with `#` in order to test. Do you know how can I see if there is a problem (log file, etc.)?

Comment: Is there a similar method for `Sleep` as well? the sleep option disappears once you clicked shutdown.

Comment: @RápliAndrás That sounds like different bug, that should be reported.

Comment: This also works for 14.04 with Xfce...

Comment: Thank you for the hint about Secure Boot. You should put that section in bold. I was going out of my mind trying to figure out why I could not hibernate after cloning my hard drive.

Comment: I totally forgot to ensure that my Secure Boot is disabled until I see this answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you still have problems in making hibernate work, check [comment #58 on this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1232814/comments/58):

> I found a workaround on ubuntu gnome 13.10: just install hibernate:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install hibernate
> ```
>
> The only problem is that apport will issue three errors when starting
>   up after normal Power Off. For this you can disable apport:
>
> ```
> sudo -H gedit /etc/default/apport
> ```
>
> Then change `enabled=0`.
>
> To change settings from hibernate edit files in `/etc/hibernate`.

Installing hibernate package seems to make the right changes and it worked very well for me in ubuntu gnome 13.10 x64

Answer (score 1):

If you have followed the previous steps and it still hasnt worked, 
I suggest that you change your `/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_custom-ehci_hcd` to:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

to make it work, then follow the steps mentioned above to enable 
the hibernate option. This really worked for me.

At the end you are gonna have 2 files edited with  "`[Re-enable hibernate ... ]`" Try this one. It will work for sure if you are using ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would like to add here, which AFAICR, is unmounted swap partition. If the swap partition is not mounted the hibernate option will not be displayed/enabled irrespective of the hibernation configuration.

And if the swap partition doesn't automount then the hibernated session would be lost.