# How to enable hibernate on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: power-management, hibernate

Something I usually do after installing Ubuntu is reactivate the hibernation function. I find it quite useful to function for the more energy concious.

Typically, I'd complete the instructions in this tutorial for Ubuntu 12.04 and I'd be back in business. However, it does seem to work any more. Any suggestions?

http://www.howtogeek.com/113923/how-to-re-enable-hibernate-in-ubuntu-12.04/

`sudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`

```
[Enable Hibernate]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Comment: This would be very helpful as suspend does not work on my machine at all.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution, https://askubuntu.com/a/362499/193491. I've paraphrased the solution below:

`sudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`

Paste the following and save the file.

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Restart the machine. The run `sudo killall indicator-session-service` once you've entered a new session, and then you'll have your hibernate functionality back.

Comment: I've restarted my machine a couple of times and the hibernate options has disappeared form the drop down menu. Running `sudo killall indicator-session-service` returns the option. Not what you'd call convenient.

Comment: It means every time we turn on the computer we should run "sudo killall indicator-session-service"? isn't it a bad solution?

Comment: It's not a solution, it's still just a workaround until the bug that causes the menu to not be properly assembled is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

seems there is possibly no need for this in 13.10  [as was not the case in 12.04.12.10.13.04]

sudo pm-hibernate

works straight off on a clean install

installing qshutdown    is also of great help as a gui to use hibernate on timer

Comment: This is an interesting work around. However it doesn't add hibernate back into the 'system' menu with: Log Out, Suspend and Shutdown.

Comment: `pm-hibernate` worked in 13.04 too.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the way explained in this link , it may work :
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/10/enable-hibernation-ubuntu-13-10/

Comment: Please avoid poor sources, this site recommends using `sudo gedit`. One must be pretty ignorant when running such a site and still doing this. http://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default-in-13-04

Comment: OK , I didn't know its not true to give the link of a page contains solution of problem . Thanks

Comment: No problem, were all here to learn new things.