# Can't hibernate on lid close 13.10

Tags: hibernate

I've recently upgraded to 13.10 and I can't find the option to hibernate. My computer doesn't play ball when I suspend it (screen doesn't reactivate upon lifting the lid) so in 13.04 I always used hibernate when lid closes. That option has now disappeared. When I go to power options the option to hibernate is not listed under "Close lid" actions. The only options are suspend and do nothing. I had this same problem with 13.04 but did the following to fix it:

Altered the file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` to say

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

I've tried this again after the update and it doesn't appear to be solving the problem.

Comment: Try 'sudo apt-get update' 'sudo apt-get upgrade' sometimes it magically works

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice but sadly it didn't help.

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/361734/169736

Answer (score 4):

The same issue on my laptop. After upgrading to 13.10 Hibernate option disappeared in Power Settings -> when the lid is closed.

Did as mentioned in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1232814
I.e

In file /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla

put this

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

After rebooting Hibernate menu reappeared in Menu. But still unavailable in Power Settings -> when the lid is closed

Comment: To finish this action and enable lid hibernate follow http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/12/change-behavior-when-lid-is-closed/