# Hibernate missing in login screen

Tags: 14.04, login-screen, hibernate, policykit

[Re-enabling hibernation by adding a rule to policy kit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361734/hibernation-is-still-missing-from-menu-in-13-10-after-enabling-via-polkit-how-t) added the option to hibernate to the desktop session as expected, but not for the login screen.

**How can I enable hibernation right from the login screen on 14.04?**

Comment: Which Display Manager are you using?

Comment: I'm using lightdm.

Comment: is the graphic card driver installed ?

Comment: Did you check #pm-hibernate working fine ?

Comment: Yes, as I said, hibernation works fine, but the hibernate is missing in login screen.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/462472/xubuntu-14-04-how-to-enable-hibernate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The address of the policy kit file changed in Ubuntu 14.04.**

Follow the [same steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/362499/94891) as before, except replacing the file:

```
/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-local.d/hibernate.pkla
```

with this one:

```
/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/hibernate.pkla
```

Try this one

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-local.d/hibernate.pkla
```

Finally, 'restart' nautilus by executing `nautilus -q` and the indicator option should spring up.

Comment: I tried this in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 and this is not working... I modified the file at

/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/hibernate.pkla

but nothing happens when I reboot. From the information in another blog, I modified the content of the following file,,

/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla

This is also not working... Which is the correct file, why this isn't working for me? @DusanMilosevic

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but still for those who are facing this issue: In ubuntu 14.04 LTS, the correct path is `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`. And you have to enable `ResultActive=yes` at **TWO** places in that file: both for `upower` and `logind`. Perhaps, that's the reason why it wasn't working for @Erdnase .

Answer (score 13):

Here is a solution. Hibernate option in **desktop session** and **login screen** as below:

**Desktop Session :**

[image]

**Login Screen :**

[image]

First open your terminal and add the following :

[image]

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

A txt file now is opened add the following lines :

[image]

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

**Save** and **reboot** your system after that hibernate should appear and function well.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not help. Nothing has changed.

Comment: i have tried on a clean copy of ubuntu 12.04 and 13.10 and it worked charmed on both , try to undo any changes you have made before , it should work

Comment: you can see i paste to screen shot and they appear on my system man !

Comment: Could you verify? There is a hibernate when I restart computer, bu not when I log out or switch account. That's the problem.

Comment: i told you maybe you use different way that conflict my solution just  undo them and try this

Comment: As you can see in my question, I have already tried that and didn't work for login screen.. I'm using 13.10

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13279/discussion-between-nux-and-dusan-milosevic)

Comment: That works fine in Ubuntu 14.04, both in desktop and in login screen. Before doing this, it may be useful to check that the computer can hibernate. Try __sudo pm-hibernate__ from terminal. If that doesn't work, make sure your swap partition is at least as large as your memory: hibernation works by copying the content of the memory to the swap.

Answer (score 9):

The configuration for hibernation already sits in file

```
/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
```

Just open this file and enable hibernation: `ResultActive=yes`
The resulting code looks like this:

```
[Disable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

and

```
[Disable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

That's all. Now you will see hibernate option in power dialog and login

Comment: This should be the top and accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

That's a bug, which will hopefully be solved in Ubuntu 14.04. It is impossible to enable hibernation in login screen.

Comment: isn't it enabled as my answer ?

Comment: Maybe the bug doesn't effect all users.

Comment: Got a link to the bug?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a multiple-user setup in Ubuntu, you´ll need to also add this snippet:

```
[Re-enable hibernate for multiple users by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=yes
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me. I believe that most if not all Ubuntu systems these days are "multiple-user", even if there is only one user account set up.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why hibernation is not present is because Ubuntu’s Hibernate feature has always not been working well in many computers. For new hardware models, the Hibernate feature often don’t work by default. In some instances, the Hibernate feature will even lead to data loss.

But if u wish to use it u can do as follows:

1. Hibernation is in "Power -> When power is critically low".
2. to include hibernation button:

   First test whether your computer supports hibernation by typing the following codes in the terminal:

   ```
   pm-hibernate
   ```

   if it goes to hibernation follow the next step:

   a. open the file :

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
   ```

   b. then edit as follows:

   ```
   [Re-enable hibernate by default]
   Identity=unix-user:*
   Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
   ResultActive=yes
   ```

Comment: This is not what I asked. Please remove this answer, as it does not answer my question. Hibernation works fine for me, but hibernation button is missing in login screen.

Comment: I think this answer is OK for people who don't care that much for hibernation and would rather keep the system stable. I for one decided to ditch hibernation after reading it.