# Xubuntu 14.04: how to enable hibernate?

Tags: xubuntu, 14.04, hibernate

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 64 bit. I know that question been asked a billion times, but all of them consist of editing following file:

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

That file does not exist on my system. I tried `com.xubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` but doesn't exist either, `locate` command doesn't find it.

Comment: Where did you read this file must be exist? I've created it, put the commands into and hibernate works fine on Xubuntu. `To do that, use your favorite text editor to create /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla. Add the following to the file and save:...` [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html)

Comment: @Simptnon but that file contains a billion other lines than the hibernate, anyway I found it, but weirdly, `locate` didn't if it wasn't for mitch i would never find it

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo nano /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
```

Look for

```
[Disable hibernate by default in upower]
[Disable hibernate by default in logind]
```

Change the value of "ResultActive=no" to "ResultActive=yes" in both, press ctrl+x to exit the file. It will ask to save the change or not. Press Y to save the change, if you're on Ubuntu restart your system.

**Edit**

Just tried this on Xubuntu 16.04, and Ubuntu 16.04. and it also works.

[image]

For Ubuntu 16.04 I had to reboot for it to work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: two questions why `locate com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla` does not find it? and why is hibernate disabled by default?

Comment: As far as the first one, use `sudo locate com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`, and it will find it.  As for the second one I really don't know for sure, but it might be a bug.

Comment: why using `sudo`? I used to search for files in `/etc` and `var` without using `sudo`

Comment: If you look at the folder the file is in, its owned by root.  I tried it, and it works with sudo.

Comment: yes I just tried it too and it works too but all I'm saying that I can search for files, say `php.ini` which is located in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and it works without `sudo` and as far as I know, `etc` is also owned by root.

Comment: If you look at the `polkit-1` folder, you will see an X on the folder, which means that you are neither the owner nor in the group that has permissions to read/write/execute to that particular folder/file.  Where as `/etc` does not.

Comment: Without using sudo the file doesn't exist for me, but shows up once i add sudo to the command

Comment: finally. best answer ever. other solutions does not work for me. many thanks.

Comment: Edits of a package owned file in `/var`, as in this solution, will be wiped out next time the package is updated. Better to create a file in `/etc` as showed in the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html).

Comment: @Lynob, for why they are disabled by default, see here (https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/bugs) under the section titled, "Hibernate and suspend don't always work well: they make some computers malfunction or even enter a coma".

Comment: This also works for Kubuntu 16.04

Comment: I double-checked the polkit-1 entries - hibernation is/was not disabled in that file, but it's been missing from my power manager for as long as I can remember. Are there any other culprits? In general I feel like this is a very silly configuration, especially as a default - I can't imagine why a guest/unauth would have more privileges than a user, nor any scenario where authorized users would be prevented from logging out and granting themselves whatever privileges follow this pattern. I see this is supposed to protect the session, but *from the owner?*

Comment: From [this page](https://zedt.eu/tech/linux/enable-hibernation-xubuntu-16-04/) it appears the label "disable by default" does *not* imply that "yes" corresponds to disabling hibernation. Serves me right for assuming...

Comment: I just want to confirm that this solution works also on Xubuntu 20.04. Thanks for it!

Answer (score 0):

For a novice like me, I would like to add:

"Just press Ctrl+Alt+T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

sudo nano /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla

Look for

[Disable hibernate by default in upower]
[Disable hibernate by default in logind]

Change the value of "ResultActive=no" to "ResultActive=yes" in both, and then restart your system."

.....before restarting the system, you should press ctrl+x to exit the file. Then it will ask for Yes or No to save the change. If you don't save the change, it will not work. I am using ChaletOS which is based on Xubuntu. It doesn't need a restart.