# How to enable hibernation on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, power-management, hibernate, secure-boot

I know there are lots of threads about this already, but none of them works for me. I tried the solution mentioned here:

- [How to enable hibernation in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762004/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-16-04)
- [Xubuntu 14.04: how to enable hibernate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462472/xubuntu-14-04-how-to-enable-hibernate)
- [How to enable hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation)
- [Hibernation is still missing from menu in 13.10 after enabling via polkit. How to enable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361734/hibernation-is-still-missing-from-menu-in-13-10-after-enabling-via-polkit-how-t)
- [How can I hibernate on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04)

This is what I tried:

1) `sudo pm-hibernate`
doesn't do anything.

2) `sudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`

That file now looks like this:

> [Re-enable hibernate by default in upower] Identity=unix-user:*
>   Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate ResultActive=yes
>
> [Re-enable hibernate by default in logind] Identity=unix-user:*
>   Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
>   ResultActive=yes
>
> [Re-enable hibernate by default for login1]   Identity=unix-user:*
>   Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate   ResultActive=yes
>
> [Re-enable hibernate for multiple users by default in logind]
>   Identity=unix-user:*
>   Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
>   ResultActive=yes

I also changed the file to this:

> [Re-enable hibernate by default in upower] Identity=unix-user:*
>   Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate ResultActive=yes
>
> [Re-enable hibernate by default in logind] Identity=unix-user:*
>   Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
>   ResultActive=yes

... but still, it doesn't work.

3) `sudo update-grub` still no hibernate option in the menu

4) Installed tuxonice

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tuxonice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tuxonice-userui linux-generic-tuxonice linux-headers-generic-tuxonice
```

Then `sudo pm-hibernate`. No results

5) `sudo apt-get install hibernate` then `sudo systemctl hibernate` I get this error message:

> Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb not supported

6) `sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla` then looked for

```
[Disable hibernate by default in upower] 
[Disable hibernate by default in logind]
```

...and changed `ResultActive=no` to `ResultActive=yes`

Additional information:

- After executing the steps above and restarting my PC for every steps I mentioned above, hibernate still doesn't show up.
- Ubuntu 16.04; Intel® Kabylake GT2
- I'm using an SSD
- My swap is larger than my mem (tested with `free`).
- `sudo locate pm-suspend.log` doesn't result in anything after executing `sudo pm-hibernate`
- I executed `dmesg` before and after executing `sudo pm-hibernate` and compared the two outputs of `dmesg`. Both outputs are identical

EDIT:

I think I found the reason: You have to **disable the secure boot option** in the BIOS. To do that, interrupt the normal boot process and it is in the option secure boot.

Comment: This is correct. Secure Boot disables hibernation. Write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the reason: You have to **disable the secure boot option** in the BIOS. To do that, interrupt the normal boot process and it is in the option secure boot.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or by searching for terminal in the Dash.

Type `sudo systemctl hibernate` into the terminal and press Enter.
Enter your password when prompted.

After you computer turns off, switch it back on. Did your open applications re-open?

If the hibernate test works, you can continue to use the `sudo systemctl hibernate` command when you want to hibernate.

You can also enable the hibernate option in the menus. To do that, use your favorite text editor to create `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`. Add the following to the file and save:

```ini
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes
```

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html)

Comment: I wonder why was this downvoted, as it may seem elegant to just need a single command :-)

Comment: As @matt states, `sudo systemctl hibernate` works well, though it requires a password entry (not necessarily a bad thing, since PW entry serves as a reminder that your caching, perhaps unencrypted, the current system state).