# Hibernation and suspension problems in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu, shutdown, lxde

I have problems when suspending and hibernating my computer when using Lubuntu 14.04. I click the shutdown icon in the lower right corner off the screen, and when I choose Hibernate, I get an error:`GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Operation not permitted`, even when I am signed in as an administrator user. However, a graphical bug happens when I choose Suspend. I click Suspend, and my whole screen is "divided" depending on where my cursor is on my screen. When I move my cursor (which is not visible), the area underneath my cursor is black (again, the cursor is not visible but I know where it is), and the area above where my cursor is is just my ordinary desktop, except everything is flashing and moving from right to left, like  how some really old TVs have a picture that moves and flickers from bottom to top or the other way around. I know describing what is happening is confusing, but stay with me. When I move my cursor to the top of the screen, my entire desktop looks normal again and is visible and normal, but my cursor is invisible. To the right of my cursor, there are a bunch of gray lines. It is really weird and the only way to stop it (as far as I know right now) is to restart the machine. What is up with my computer and what do I need to do to fix either problems?

Comment: The suspend issue seems to be a bug. For hibernating you should check the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html) if you haven't already. Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/361734

Comment: please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/685264/hybernate-doesnt-work-with-lubuntu-14-04-03-lts/685267#685267)