# Hybernate doesn't work with Lubuntu 14.04.03 LTS

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, hibernate

When I click on "Hibernate" (S3) (in German it is: "Ruhezustand") in the LogOff Screen in Lubuntu 14.04.3 LTS I got this error.

> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied

How can I solve this to use the hibernation-mode?

`sudo pm-hibernate` work without problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reference to : [lxsession/+bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxsession/+bug/1300798), this seems to be a bug.

There is a similar question in Ask Ubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453259/hibernation-and-suspension-problems-in-lubuntu-14-04).

*Test if hibernate works*.

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

If the `hibernate` test works, you can continue to use the `sudo pm-hibernate` command when you want to`hibernate`.

You can also enable the hibernation option in the menu.

Create the file :

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

Add the following lines:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Save and exit.

Comment: `systemd-shim` is still installed. Are you sure about `/etc/pam.d/lxdm`? It doesn't exist. But `/etc/pam.d/lightmd` exists. I added the line there. And for testing I created `lxdm` and added the line there, too (as root of course). Doesn't work. The problem is still the same.

Comment: `systemd` doesn't work in _14.04_.

Comment: @buhtz does it working in  terminal `sudo pm-hibernate` ?

Comment: The `[Re-enable hibernate by default]` worked fine. Thanks!