# Hibernate option missing from menu

Tags: hibernate

Running 14.04.1 LTS (kernel 3.13.0-53)

Since updating to 3.13.0-53 the hibernate menu option has gone awol. I have tested that `pm-hibernate` still works and that swap is larger than memory. I did notice that the polkit-1 override had mysteriously disappeared and so I replaced it.

```
$ ls -l /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 244 May 20 18:47 com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

I know there are plenty of similar questions been asked before and I have searched most of them for an answer to no avail.

So what has broken it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/questions/361734/hibernation-is-still-missing-from-menu-in-13-10-after-enabling-via-polkit-how-t/362499#362499

Comment: Yes, tried all that and it still is not available from the menu.