# Hibernation kills all programs

Tags: 15.04, swap, hibernate

Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361734/hibernation-is-still-missing-from-menu-in-13-10-after-enabling-via-polkit-how-t/362499#362499) answer I was able to restore hibernation on my Ubuntu Vivid Vervet 15.04. Unfortunately after hiberate/restore all running programs are gone, as if it was a regular power-off.

Any hints?

Edit:

> sudo blkid

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="c5d5f237-f70c-43db-bbeb-482b8c15bf33" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="559a5acb-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="60a90294-7412-47fc-99e3-f2c69a9b1db0" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="559a5acb-05"
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="6d0b5a7c-f404-47e9-a641-b04dcde3a5c2" TYPE="swap"
```

> cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume

```
RESUME=UUID=645b50f6-d568-4247-9f7b-a6bd07b21686
```

Comment: Do you have a swap partition? What is it size? What is your RAM size?

Comment: @Pilot6 I have a 4.2 GB swap and 3.8 GB RAM

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` terminal commands.

Comment: @alex does this still happen when running `sudo pm-hibernate`?

Comment: What is your "cryptswap" partition for?

Comment: @Grammargeek yes, it does

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't really know as it is not my laptop

Comment: The system setup is not standard, that's the problem. I do not know if hibernation is feasible with encrypted swap.

Answer (score 2):

You hibernation does not work because you have a wrong UUID in your `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file.

Run in terminal

```
echo "RESUME=UUID=60a90294-7412-47fc-99e3-f2c69a9b1db0" | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Comment: But I am concerned about "cryptswap". Is your swap partition /dev/sda5 or you have an encrypted swap?

Comment: this does not work for me - the same problems occur.  do you have any other ideas?

Comment: The idea is same. System must know from what partition to resume. If swap is encrypted, that may be an issue. If you do not need an ancrypted swap, i would remove it and update `/etc/fstab` and other settings.

Answer (score 0):

At the [Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html), it is already warned that hibernation may not work as expected, and suggests that test run before activating, and always save the work you are doing.

This is why the feature is not enabled by default.

Comment: That is true, but it works in most cases.