# Do I need a separate swap partition for hibernation or I may use usual system swap partition?

Tags: 19.04, swap, hibernate

I use Ubuntu 19.04.

I have not enough physical memory (only 8 GB), thus I regularly use swap partition to extend my virtual memory. (Swap partition size is ≈ 9 GB.)

And now I want to set up hibernation.

My question is: how am I supposed to set it all up, so that Ubuntu could save memory state to disk and not to overwrite my existing swap data?

Do I have to create a separate swap partition?

And what if currently (right in this second) my virtual memory usage is less than 8 GB, but some data is still saved in swap partition (e.g. memory usage is 4 GB of 8 (50%), but swap partition usage is 10%)  - will I be able to hibernate using that swap partition right now?

How do I set it all up?

Comment: Your *swap file* or *swap partition* should big enough for normal use + the 8gb RAM you want to write to it in order to hibernate.  Hibernate will not override data already in swap; the hibernate just won't occur if there isn't enough space in swap to save all your memory (an error message will be in your logs).

Comment: Related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/361734/
You can test if hibernation works by installing `pm-utils` then type in a terminal `pm-hibernate`